# Synonyms/alternatives of "Patience"

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, slang, spoken-english

Suppose if I want someone to read a long essay that would take long get finished, what expression should I write to have patience? Because its worthwile as well.

Comment: I might say "I know it's long, but it will be worth it." or "Read the whole thing, you won't be sorry you did!"

Answer (score 2):

I assume OP's precise context requires a word to fill the blank...

> *I'd like you to read my essay. I know it's long, but please ____, because it's worthwhile.*

I personally don't think ***be patient*** is likely to be particularly suitable there, because it strongly implies the essay will be *boring, unsatisfying* (until some "punch line" right at the end, which supposedly will justify the entire reading process).

To my mind, *please **persevere*** is much better. There's still the implication that reading the essay may<sup>1</sup> require *effort* - but let's face it, great literature is more likely to be called "difficult" than "boring".

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this is just a *possible* implication. It's also possible the *only* reason perseverance might be required is because the reading will take a long time (not that it will be difficult for any *other* reason).